# Route traffic to target IP through specific NIC adapter

Tags: linux, networking, ip

I have a Raspberry Pi connected to a router via `eth0`. It also has USB LAN adapter `eth1` to which an IP Camera is attached.

I need to access the IP Camera through it's IP address, but since `eth0` is my default interface, when I try to capture stream using `vlc` it doesn't find it. When I ping it by explicitly using `eth1` it is there, so the connection to it is OK.

Is it possible to somehow tell the Linux when connecting to specific IP to use specific interface for all kind of connections or something like that?

Comment: Why not just use different subnets (like 192.168.1.0/24 and 192.168.2.0/24)? That would remove any ambiguity on where packets need to go.

Comment: @DanielB, yes, but I want to be able to plug the camera into the router if something happens with the USB adapter, so it would be ready for use with no additional configs

Comment: Sounds like a job for DHCP... But, if you set a host route to the Camera's IP via eth1  'route add -host 192.168.2.222 -interface eth1' it may do what you want.  Though if something happens to the USB interface that doesn't result in it being set 'DOWN', then the Pi won't be able to reach the ip cam if you move it to the router, until you delete the host route.

Comment: Please edit question with output of `ip addr` and `ip route`. Does the camera get the IP address per DHCP, or is it a fixed address (which one)? If everything is configured correctly, you should have a link-local route to the camera, so there's probably a configuration error.